# Assist with Drupal Admin Blank page for custom functions or code

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to learn Drupal.  What I want to do is create a backend page (that is on main menu) where I can run my own functions and code.  I have been doing research and found out that to do this I need to create a module.  And if I run the "hook_menu" function - i can get that backend page to be on the menu.  I found code for a drupal module that does this, and it loads a form for a "config settings" page.  Here is the code:

```
function add_game_menu() {

$items = array();

$items['admin/add_game'] = array(
'title' => 'Add Gm Pg',
'description' => 'Description of your add game page',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('add_game_admin'),
'access arguments' => array('administer add_game settings'),
'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

return $items;
}


function add_game_admin() {
$form = array();

$form['add_game_maxdisp'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Maximum number of links'),
'#default_value' => variable_get('add_game_maxdisp', 3),
'#size' => 2,
'#maxlength' => 2,
'#description' => t("The maximum number of links to display in the block."),
'#required' => TRUE,
 );

 return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

I modified it a little but it does work.  What I want to do is do this but run my own functions and code on here and not the "drupal_get_form" function.

I tried to do this and just created a function to echo text and then put the function name in the "page callback" field of the array.  This did work, it did execute my function on the page instead of the drupal form function, but the page was a blank white page with none of the "drupal backend styling or menus or anything"; it was literally just completely blank white webpage with just my text printed on it.

So I am thinking the "drupal_get_form" function not only puts a form on the page, but it also makes it so it is drupal backend page with proper header, footer, menus etc.

So I am thinking that i need a function like "drupal_get_form" but it has a "blank slate" where I can run whatever code or functions that I want.

Would anybody know anything about this or how to approach doing this?

Thanks so much...

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is to create a template, register it and use `theme` function in your code. You can take a look at this [Quick Introduction to Drupal's hook_menu() and hook_theme()](http://websmiths.co/blog/very-quick-introduction-drupals-hookmenu-and-hooktheme)

So your code might look like:

```
function add_game_menu() {

$items = array();

$items['admin/add_game'] = array(
  'title' => 'Add Gm Pg',
  'description' => 'Description of your add game page',
  'page callback' => 'my_function',
  'access arguments' => array('administer add_game settings'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

return $items;
}

function my_function(){
  // Call theme() function, so that Drupal includes the custom-page.tpl.php template
  return theme('my_custom_template');
}

/*
 * Implementation of hook_theme().
 */
function add_game_theme(){
  return array(
    'my_custom_template' => array(
      // template file name will be custom-page.tpl.php
      'template' => 'custom-page',
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I have made some progress on this, no success yet but progress, I have gotten it so it does create menu item and does create page which does have admin header footer menu; but i have not been able to get any code to run on the page yet; working on that...